Refrigerator water line leak
I came home to a puddle on my floor and discovered a pinhole leak in the plastic water line. The line is long so I could cut it and reattach it. The saddle valve is almost out of my reach in the ceiling of my cellar (can only get at it with my fingertips) but I was able to turn it off with a thin pvc pipe I cut slots into to fit over the handle and twist clockwise. The refrigerator was installed a month ago and at that time, the installer said the saddle valve worked fine. But water is still spraying from the pinhole in the line. Is this because pressure is still in the line? If so, how long before it stops? I’m afraid to detach the line to shorten it until I’m positive the valve is working or I’ll have a much bigger problem on my hands because the real valve is near the saddle valve but it is completely out of reach. Any advice would be appreciated asap.

if the valve is working, the water flow should stop immediately

the installer put in the fridge, and didn't do it standing in a puddle I assume.

A valve that is "completely out of reach" is useless.  either cut a new acess or get something to stand on (unclear how it's "completely out of reach" from your question.)

I’ll have a much bigger problem ... you already have it ... the water will not stop spraying from the pinhole

I was (mostly) correct... There was still pressure in the line and it eventually slowed down to barely a drip. The reason the valves are out of reach is because they are in the ceiling in my basement. Most of my basement has a drop ceiling - and panels are easy to remove... Except for the one spot where the valve is. (Of course) So I have to stand on a step stool, and reach over to it. The installer was a big guy and his arms were longer. The other valve wasn't a shut off for the fridge anyway. After further inspection I realized that valve was after the water line to the fridge and is a shut-off for my outside water spicket. The bigger problem I was worried about is if I had disconnected the line and the water wasn't actually shut off, that pinhole spray which was at least manageable with a bucket underneath would have turned into a powerful flow. That is a BIGGER PROBLEM obviously.... At any rate, I was able to cut a hole in my ceiling to get to the saddle valve, replace the line and stop the leak. Now my refrigerator won't dispense water though and I know the valve is on and water flowing all the way to the refrigerator (I checked...) So I shut off the icemaker because I'm worried that it may break if it's not getting water. I have NO IDEA WHY I can't get water... I purged it for over 5 minutes with no luck. So since the fridge was just installed, they are coming to fix it Friday since it's under warranty...

You might look into what an ellipsis is (...), and avoid using them arbitrarily.  You might also use italics for emphasis instead of YELLING. That reminds me of an old Austin Powers bit.
